# Excluding an intercept in regsubsets (leaps package)?

Tags: r

I am running some model averaging procedures using the output from the regsubsets command from the leaps package. Once I exclude an intercept, I get an error message that I cannot make sense of:

> Reordering variables and trying again: Error in if
>   (any(index[force.out] == -1)) stop("Can't force the same variable in
>   and out") :    missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

This problem seems to occur only once my predictor matrix has more columns than the dependent variable has observations (which is one of the reasons for using leaps in the first place). See the example code below:

```
# Load the package --------------------------------------------------------
require(stats)
require(leaps)

# Some artificial data ----------------------------------------------------
y <- rnorm(20)
x1  <- rnorm(20*20)
dim(x1) <- c(20,20)
x2 <- rnorm(20*21)
dim(x2) <- c(20,21)

# Allow intercept ---------------------------------------------------------
summary(regsubsets(x1,y))$which
summary(regsubsets(x2,y))$which

# Without intercept -------------------------------------------------------
summary(regsubsets(x1,y,intercept=FALSE))$which
summary(regsubsets(x2,y,intercept=FALSE))$which
```

Comment: Dimension of `x2` and `y` are not conformable.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to include "require(stats)" for random number generation in the preamble. Does it work now, @Pascal?

Comment: Ok, I get what you mean, but non-conformability is not the issue here. I am not trying to regress y on all columns of x2, that obviously does not work. regsubsets instead goes through subsets of the regressor matrix and finds the models with the best fit for each model size up to nvmax (which is 8 by default).

Answer (score 0):

This usually happens when you have a Linear Dependency in the input variables - you should see a warning , when you run it with Intercept = T. 
When you remove the linear dependent column from input predictor , you will be able to run regsubsetsObj with intercept = F . You will have manually remove the linearly dependent column . Its usually a derived column, calculated from existing metrics.